# ASP.NET MVC 4 Can't retrieve file from form

Tags: asp.net, image, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, upload

I'm working on a listings site and I'm trying to upload an image and store it's path in the database.

The problem is, I just can't seem to be able to retrieve the uploaded file from the form.

Here is the form,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Condition)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Condition)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Condition)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostedBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostedBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            Upload Image <input type="file" name="listingImage" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is the action

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase listingImage)
    {
        if (listingImage == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

I have a model for a product listing setup like so.

```
 public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }

    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}
```

Now every time I complete the form and submit listingImage is null and I'm returned to the Index.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set your form encoding type to "multipart/form-data", otherwise you cannot post files.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

And yes, you **can** define your file separately from your model data and declare controller action as you did before, no need to include file field into your model class:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase listingImage)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`listingImage` is not a part of your model, and then it does not get the same binding as the rest of the `Model.xx` properties.

You could update `Product` to include `HttpPostedFileBase listingImage` and change the controller action to

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
```

In your html you can add the new property like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){ @* Forgot this line as Alex Skalozub told in his answer  *@ 
@* code omitted *@

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.listingImage, new {type = "file"})
    </div>
}
```

For the file location and saving you could do something in the lines of

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/products"),product.listingImage.FileName);
product.listingImage.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: I tried including HttpPostedFileBase in my model but I got an error similar to something on the lines of "Key cannot be null".